# Can not pass state with react router dom v6 beta, state is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## App.js file

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="h-100">
            <Routes>
             <Link to={
                {
                    pathname: "/posts",
                    state: {test: 'test'}
                }
                }>Posts</Link>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
                <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
```

expected to pass state,some piece of data from one page to another
when using useLocation to get state from another page state is null

## index.js file

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
            <App/>
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## Posts.js file

```
const location=useLocation()
console.log(location);
```

## Output

```
Object { pathname: "/posts", search: "", hash: "", state: null, key: "hpuuzep5" }
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "chance",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can not either import switch from react-router-dom, it says switch is not exported from react router dom, I think have correctly set up my routes where is the error i can not pass state from one route to another

Comment: These are just your routes, what is the actual vs expected behavior and relevant code?

Comment: useLocations state prop is null i have to pass some data from one page to another

Comment: Then you should include the code where you are attempting to pass the data and receive the data.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: I am also getting null when I try to pass state using react-router-dom v6 beta

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was able to get state by doing this:

```
<Link
  to={"/posts"}
  state={{test: 'test'}}>
    Posts
</Link>
```

I opened the type declaration and finally realized state was a prop, and not part of the to object https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#link

Comment: Should be `state={{ test: 'test' }}>`. Need to wrap the key-value pair in `{}`.

Comment: @blackr1234 thank you! I will edit the response

Answer (score 16):

I would like to add that in Version 5 you could get the state passed to the component by the props.

Now it only works using useLocation.

**Component where the `<Link />` is**

```
<Link to={'/page1'} state={{ state: 'mystate' }} >Page 1</Link>
```

**Component where you want to get the state**

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const { state } = useLocation()
```

I found this article about that.
https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-link/

I spend to many time around this and somehow i couldn't find any information about this on the documentation.

Hope to help someone out there

Comment: in my case: const state = location.state works.

Answer (score 11):

You can also navigate to a certain path by using the `useNavigate()` hook like so:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/posts', {state: { test: 'test'}})
```

The full explanation is documented very well here:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory