# React router how to go up with link to pathname

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url, react-router

I am using the `Link` component from react router as follows

```
    <li><Link to={{
      pathname: "../photos",
      state: {
        id: props.id
      }
    }} className="nav-link active" >photos</Link></li>
```

I am using `Link` this way because I need to pass in some data to the linked component. The linked component exists on a route one level above the current route, hence the two dots and a slash `../` However, when clicked I'm not taken to a level above the current route, but rather `/photos` is appended to the end of the current route. If I use `Link` in this manner

```
<li><Link to="../photos" className="nav-link active" >photos</Link></li>
```

then it works as expected, but I am unable to pass data through. I don't understand why there is a discrepancy.

-----------------------EDIT--------------------------

Here is the solution [Can not pass state with react router dom v6 beta, state is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061088/can-not-pass-state-with-react-router-dom-v6-beta-state-is-null)

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` and report the version. Can you also include your routing/navigation code, i.e. the router and routes and this component in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I found the answer in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061088/can-not-pass-state-with-react-router-dom-v6-beta-state-is-null

Comment: I see, so `react-router-dom@6`. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score -2):

Use absolute path. For example;

```
pathname: "/dashboard/users/5/photos"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just appends the absolute path to the end of the current path