# Issues while trying to pass data from one page to another using Link from React-Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have the following Router:

```
// index.js  



 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; 
    import history from "./history";
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    
    root.render(
    
        <Router history={history}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/Page1' element={<Page1/>} />
                <Route path='/Page2' element={<Page2/>} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    
    );

    // history.js
    
        import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
        
        export default createBrowserHistory();
```

I'm trying to pass data from Page1 to Page2 using `<Link>` from React-Router V6. To be more explicit, I'm doing this because Page1 contains a list of participants, each with an edit button. When the edit button is clicked, Page2 opens. Page2 is a form containing the data of the participant you want to edit. Here is a picture so you can visualize it.

[image]

**Page1 is a class component** while **Page2 is a functional component with Hooks** so that I can call useLocation(). After I retrieve the data from Page1, I want to pre-complete the form. Page2 is a functional component because in React-Router V6, you can only do this using useLocation() hook, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061088/can-not-pass-state-with-react-router-dom-v6-beta-state-is-null/70306547#70306547)

***A) Page1 where I'm passing the data to Page2***

```
//Page1


class CandidatesList extends Component {

 // ...

 listOfParticipants = this.state.listOfParticipants.map((participant) => {
 return(
 <Link to="/Page2" state={{participant: participant}} className="btn btn-primary">Edit Participant</Link> 
 // This is the edit button that opens Page2 while passing the data 

 )


}
```

***B) Page2 where I'm retrieving the data from Page1***

```
///////////// Page2

    // ...

    function Page2() {
    
    const { state } = useLocation()
    console.log(state.participant) // 

    useEffect(() => {
    /// ...

    }

}
```

However, it seems that the data is never received in Page2 and I get the following error (when I try to `console.log()` it)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'participant')
```

**What am I doing wrong and why is the data not getting passed?**

Comment: Which `Router` is being imported and used? Can you share an example `participant` object value that is being passed in state? Is it a serializable object?

Comment: import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; 

It does not have anything to do with the object itself. I tried passing a primitive instead of a participant and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Is the `EditCandidates` component ***the*** `Page2` component in `index.js`?

Comment: It is indeed. Sorry for the mistake, that was actually Page2, therefore function Page2() , I edited my original question.

Comment: FWIW I can't seem to reproduce the null state in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/issues-while-trying-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-using-link-from-react-05tjc7?file=/src/App.js), it's passed from Page1 to Page2. It's possible it's the way you are logging `console.log(state.participant)` as an unintentional side-effect, or not using a null check on the route state. You can see how I've correctly logged the state in a `useEffect` hook and check that `state` exists first before accessing into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the culprit, which should have been obvious and is a stupid mistake on my side...

My `useEffect()` function contains the following

```
   // Page2
   function Page2() {

       const {
           state
       } = useLocation()
       console.log(state.participant) 


       let someAsyncResult;
       useEffect(() => {
           if (!window.location.hash) {
               window.location = window.location + '#dataLoaded';
               window.location.reload();
           }
           async function fetchFromContract() {

               someAsyncResult = await remoteObject.fetchSomeRemoteStuff();
               // ... also setting state here using the someAsyncResult 

           }
           fetchFromContract();

       }, [])

   }
```

I'm doing the window.location stuff because otherwise I'd have to manually refresh the page anytime in order for `someAsyncResult` to get rendered. The page renders without it beforehand.

**Anyway, so what is happening is that because the route becomes */Page2#dataLoaded*** after the async stuff is done, Page2 doesn't receive the props anymore since `<Link>`in Page1 referred to ***/Page2*** not ***/Page2#dataLoaded***